# Dynamically add Edit Text and have their references

Tags: java, android, mobile-application

I want to be able to add Edit Texts at run time and also have their references with a click on some button. What would be the best possible way of implementing it?

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle about with this:

```
private void buildEditText() {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    EditText editText = (EditText) inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout, null); // Here is your reference
    LayoutParams textViewParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    editText .setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
    layout.addView(textView);
    this.editText = editText ;
    this.editText .setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    editText .setText("If you have some text to enter");

    editText .setHint("Some hint");
    editText .setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS); 

    parentView.addView(layout);
}
```